# Xcode server not working after Xcode update

Tags: xcode, xcode-bots, xcode9.3

After updating Xcode to 9.3, my bots disappeared and there's a messenger symbol at the right. How can I restore the bots?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, I have to turn on Xcode Server in two places. Then it worked as expected

*preferences > Server & Bots*
[image]

*preferences > Accounts > Xcode Servers*
[image]

Comment: I have found this to be the case with even x.x.1 updates to Xcode. Server-related preferences tend to get turned off or even removed entirely (i.e. Xcode Servers list becomes blank)